# How to Re-Show and Restore Previously Added Fragment with its View to Container

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Here I am having code (function) for loading the fragment into container...

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment targetFragment, int containerId) {

    if (!targetFragment.isAdded()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Adding First Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(containerId, targetFragment,targetFragment.getClass().getName()).commit();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Showing The Privious Instance of Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(targetFragment.getClass().getName())).commit();
    }

}
```

The issue with code is`if part` is working correctly , if there is no instance added of fragment it simply adds that fragment instance , but when I try to reload that fragment nothing happens, seems like I have made mistake with `else part` to load the previously added fragment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few experiments !

Here is the best solution I have found !

**Whenever Fragment reloads onCreate function is called which returns the view , so instead of creating new instance of view everytime , return the previous instance !**

```html
    
public class AnyFragment extends Fragment {

    //View of Fragment
    private View viewObj=null;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //insted of inflating new view it will check for the previous view as well
        if(viewObj==null){
        viewObj= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_output_sequeleye, container, false);
       }

        return viewObj;
    }
}
```

Also in activity , instead of creating new instance every time , use only single instance created initially , as below !

```html
    
public class AnyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //instance created
    AnyFragment anyFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

       //initializing the intsance        
       anyFrag=new AnyFragment()
       
       //using the privious ariable again insted of making new instance
       loadFragment(anyFrag,R.id.CONTAINERID);
       
    }


    //Your function which loads the fragment
    public void loadFragment(Fragment targetFragment, int containerId) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, targetFragment, targetFragment.getClass().getName()).commit();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem in your code:
**You forgot to use detach method before attach**

in your code:

```
     if (!targetFragment.isAdded()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adding First Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(containerId, targetFragment,targetFragment.getClass().getName()).commit();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Showing The Privious Instance of Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .detach(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(targetFragment.getClass().getName()))    

.attach(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(targetFragment.getClass().getName()))
        .commit();
            }
```

Comment: I Tried that but didn't seems to be working ! By Using First Detach and Then Attach it will not reuse the previous view state of fragment ! I want to retain the state as well that's why I tried to put the only attach !!!

Comment: for reuse the previous view state of fragment you should save states by sharedPreference and read states from shared preference

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to use it ! I want to keep running  the fragment which was back grounded !

Comment: ok...in your code in else block remove your code and only read from sharedPreferece and set new value for fragment views...
what is new value? new value is save in sharedPreference when view state changed...
This means that you should only refresh the views

Comment: I agree with your comment but mate actually I have object Animator as well inside it which depends on some process and that process keep updating the values of progress bar inside the fragment ! If will detach the fragment then store the values to the bundle or shared preferences , then it might drop null reference error as well